# Bitbucket branch misalignment and conflicts

Tags: git, bitbucket, branching-and-merging, merge-conflict-resolution, git-workflow

I am experiencing strange behavior of Git/Bitbucket.
We are a small team of developers working using following workflow:

All features are developed in branches started from `master`.
And we have a `production` branch.
So to publish a feature we create 2 PRs in Bitbucket:
`feature-branch -> master`
`master -> production`
It's often that there are multiple features being developed in parallel, so we have to make sure that feature branches are aligned to master before merging the PR. Sometimes this requires resolving conflicts.

**The things we observe:**

- Once creating the PR `master -> production` Bitbucket shows message:

> X commits behind "production".Sync now.

- Sometimes there is a conflict between `master` and `production` which is always trivially resolved.
- When creating the PR Bitbucket generates commit message automatically and every time it contains commits that were merged before.
  This happens even if i create PR when branches are aligned, which can be confirmed by the fact that diff is empty.

What could be a cause to the above? I can't figure out.
To my understanding there should be no conflict or misalignment between `master` and `production` as we don't commit to `production` directly.

The settings we use for PR and branch management:
[image]

[image]

Comment: It might help to get an overview of what your repo's history ends up looking like to work out what's going on.
It's also possible that it's just listing the merge commits.

Comment: @Ripp_, am i right that i should expect to see only the merge commits in both master and production?

Comment: @Ripp_ a little followup - i have few commits i did right to master, without creating a PR.

Comment: Note that a squash merge is not a merge, it's a plain commit. That's fine if that's what you want. In any case when you make a *new* commit on `master`, that causes `master` to move ahead one commit, because you just made a new commit *on* `master` and the definition of making a commit on some branch is that the new commit is now the last commit on the branch (whereas just a moment ago, some earlier commit was the last commit on the branch). So you should always expect this kind of thing, *unless* you don't make *any* new commit (which requires not doing a merge *or* a squash merge).

Comment: The only way to merge without either using a merge commit or a squash commit is to *fast-forward* (or rebase onto master and then fast-forward, but that also ends with a fast-forward operation). That *also* advances `master` but now it advances it to be *even with* the branch you fast-forward-"merged". (A fast forward operation is not really a merge at all, it's just that Git uses the awkward phrase *fast forward merge* to describe it, so we end up with this weird non-merge "merge" that's so hard to wrap your head around.)